# Disable "open with" in chrome

Tags: chrome-for-android

How do I disable the "open with" feature in chrome on android? An alternative would be to have chrome itself in the list of alternatives.

Comment: Can you please rephrase the question as it is unclear. Do you want to stop Chrome opening web pages by default, and instead prompt you how you want to open a link?

Comment: No, but I want the option of opening a link in chrome itself.

Comment: Does it currently open somewhere else? You can set your default apps in Settings > Apps.

Comment: I am only getting the option to open some links using external apps even if chrome would be able to open them itself.

Comment: When you have an app installed which is a dedicated app to handle certain links, you'll be given options how you want to open it. Example, if you have twitter app installed and you tap on a twitter link, it can sometimes ask you where you want to open it. You can set them in Settings > default Apps > Opening Links and set "Open supported links" to "Don't open in this app".

Comment: I know all of this. The problem is that I cannot open those links in chrome, given the options presented.

Answer (score 3):

Apps has an option as 'In-App Browser' which enables an app to open links within the app and it can be disabled by disabling 'In-App Browser' in that particular Settings of App.

For another thing like clicking twitter links, for ex-  'https://t.co/something' we have two ways either clear default app in settings that enables system to ask you from which app you want to complete this task or copy the link(s) and open it in browser itself.